# Xilinx ISE build time and already compiled modules

Tags: xilinx

Is there a way to speed up Xilinx ISE build process? I have multiple verilog HDL files in my project. Sometimes I implement a minor change in at a place in one file. However the build time is same as if the whole project were changed. I think software does not offer any advantage for already build modules.

I know its hardware, but is there some way out. I am really trouble with my slow progress. Any other tips to make the process will be appreciated.

Yours Truely

Abu Bakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things you can do to speed up an FPGA build. Among them:
 - floorplanning
 - design partitioning (Xilinx and Altera have some differences)
 - adding false paths and mulitcycle paths constraints
 - playing with synthesis and physical implementation tool options
 - choice of the reset scheme can also affect the build time
 - not over-constraining timing

I discuss this very topic in more detail in my book.

Thanks.

Comment: Dear Evgeni Stavinov, Thank you for the tips. Google has returned quite useful material for the list shared by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can partition the design to help speed up the place and route process in a large design.  But to be honest, FPGA builds are always going to be pretty lengthy :(

That's why most of us start out doing builds and debugging on the bench and *very* quickly move to debugging the code in a simulator (which is very fast to compile - seconds), and only when it works there doing the loooong build for silicon (hours).

Comment: Dear Mr. Martin, Thanks for your comment. I downloaded iverilog to compile and simulate my project in DOS command prompt. Its faster but sometimes even the correctly compiled is not good enought for build process. Therefore I have to keep checking after every new module weather or not it is Synthesizable . You mentioned partitioning. Does it mean that I do it with more than one project? I am doing it with too much copy-pasting and it just gets annoying, especially for the constraint file. I am a java programmer and am looking for "hardware reusability" in HDL design.

Comment: Hardware reusability comes from functions/procedures (like in Java) and entities/modules, which are hardware specific.  To be honest, it sounds like you're just going up the normal "SW guy moving to HW" learning curve, figuring out what's synthesisable or not, keep persevering.